# Add a sub collection in Add-WebConfigurationProperty

Tags: powershell, iis

There is multiple exemple of setting IIS Configuration painstakingly using multiple Add/Set-WebConfigurationProperty to iterate within rewrite rule for exemple.

It seem to me that most of it is doable in one command, however i'm stuck on adding the "conditions" collection, if anyone venture an idea...

Here is my current "state of affair":

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webserver/rewrite/GlobalRules" -name "." -value @{
        name="Protocol-Version Blocking Rule"; 
        stopProcessing='True';
        match=@{
          url=".*"
        };
        conditions=@{
            logicalGrouping="MatchAll";
            add=@{input="{SERVER_PROTOCOL}"; pattern="HTTP/0.8";} # (tried that since the xml tag is <add> but doesn't work/do anything)
        };
        action=@{
            type="CustomResponse";
            statusCode=505;
            statusReason="HTTP Version Not Supported";
            statusDescription="Wazaaa.";
        }
    }
# that work obviously but is kinda cumbersome ...
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter 'system.webserver/rewrite/GlobalRules/rule[@name="Protocol-Version Blocking Rule"]/conditions' -name "." -value @{input="{SERVER_PROTOCOL}"; pattern="HTTP/0.9";}
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter 'system.webserver/rewrite/GlobalRules/rule[@name="Protocol-Version Blocking Rule"]/conditions' -name "." -value @{input="{SERVER_PROTOCOL}"; pattern="HTTP/1.0";}
```

Comment: I don't have a better idea, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: @silmaril: Did you finally find a solution?

Comment: Hi @markuss, sadly no, i settled on the extra commands for the differents conditions sadly ...
but i don't have to play with IIS anymore so this is only bad memories now ^^